# Composite custom aspx page title issue

Tags: c1-cms

We have build a custom aspx pages inside the composite. The problem is the page title or tab title is stuck at Loading... all the time. We tried everything from .NET side but it still doesnt go away. Any hints ?

Composite C1 2.1.1
Build no. 2.1.4113.99

Answer (score 1):

From http://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/279386

For page to be loaded correctly, you have to add some C1 specific markup. This also gives the benefit of full access to the Javascript environment where you can manipulate the trees, open dialogs, update the message queue etc.

The following thing has to be added as a minimum
 To the beginning:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:control="http://www.composite.net/ns/uicontrol">
<control:httpheaders runat="server" />
```

Into the <head> section:

```
<control:scriptloader type="sub" runat="server" />
```

Inside of the <body> section:

```
<body>

 <ui:page id="..."> .. </ui:page>

</body>
```

Here's a diff of before and after: http://compositec1contrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/0b7bb354faf2#Sorting%2fPackage%2fComposite%2fInstalledPackages%2fCompositeC1Contrib.Sorting%2fSort.aspx